# rabbitmq using threads with pika

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, pika

I'm trying to get a basic queue system with rabbitmq, but when I try to use threads, it only seems to run 1 thread.

my code:

```
import pika
import threading

rabbit_url = "amqp://user:pass!@127.0.0.1:5672/%2f"

def start(max_threads):
    for i in xrange(max_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=run)
        t.start()
        t.join()

def run():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.URLParameters(rabbit_url))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.basic_consume(callback,
                          queue='docketq',
                          no_ack=True)

    channel.start_consuming()

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    do_work(body)

def do_work(body):
    print body
```

Answer (score 6):

`t.join()` waits for the thread to finish. In the first iteration of the loop in `start()` you start the first thread and then wait for it to finish, but it never will because `channel.start_consuming()` is an infinite loop waiting for incoming messages.

Comment: In general, place the t.start() and t.join() in the same loop, will make similar error.

Comment: How to stop `channel.start_consuming()`?

Comment: You need to import multiprocessing and In a new process use a thread as consumer.
If need to stop the start_consuming, you need to terminate the new process from the main process.

Comment: @F.Tamy can you post example code?
I am facing this issue and cant find a solution

Comment: @Gulzar can you post example code?
I am facing this issue and cant find a solution

Comment: @RandString What are you talking about?

Comment: @Gulzar how did you solve this issue?
Like how do you use catch the errors thrown by pika inside thread?
thanks

Comment: @RandString I am not the OP here. Catching errors is done the same in a thread as anywhere else, use try..except

Answer (score 5):

Pika is not threadsafe. From the [Pika FAQ](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html):

> Is Pika thread safe?
>
> Pika does not have any notion of threading in the code. If you want to use Pika with threading, make sure you have a Pika connection per thread, created in that thread. It is not safe to share one Pika connection across threads.

Comment: But no connection is shared, since the connection is created in `run`, which is executed once per thread.